# Is there a -phile suffixed word for love of devices/tools/equipment?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with a play on words with sociopath and audiophile, specifically as it pertains to audio recording devices. I've been searching for a word that I swear I've used before but have not been able to recall or find via searching, and am now afraid that the word I'm searching for is non-existent.

Comment: How about a podophile?

Comment: Love of feet? Umm... ???

Comment: Technophile? Not specific to audio, but …

Comment: There is *mechanophilia* but it includes sexual attraction to machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ralph.m states in the comments: **technophile**.

From [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/technophile):

> **technophile** (noun), a person who is enthusiastic about technology